# Creating controls dynamically at runtime

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

I have created a program to generate a label template that can be modified at run time, I am setting the dimensions of the template form,

```
public void 

    createBlankLabel(int width, int height)
    {
            Size = new Size(width, height);
            Show();
    }
```

Then when a control selection is made by clicking the relevant button on another form, I call the function to add the control on the template form.

```
public void btnRetailPrice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            blanklabel.labelMaker(4, 50, 100, 15, "RETAILPRICE");
        }
```

This is called on blanklabel (template form)

```
public void labelMaker(int x, int y, int h, int l, string labelName)
        {
            controlSelector cS = new controlSelector();
            Label lName = new Label();
            lName.Name = labelName;
            lName.Text = labelName;
            lName.AutoSize = false;
            Size dimensions = new Size(h, l);
            Point rp = new Point(x, y);
            lName.Location = rp;
            this.Controls.Add(lName);
            ControlMoverOrResizer.Init(lName);
        }
```

The problem I am having is that I can either have it generate another form of standard dimensions and the control is added to that, or it is not added to any form. How do I specify that it is added to the form that has been set to the dimensions I previously passed in? (500,250)?

Comment: Is there any specific reason for calling "controlSelector cS = new controlSelector();"?

Comment: createBlankLabel is in what class? Is it some BlankLabelForm : Form? Otherwise I expect you have to call "blanklabel.Size = new Size(width, height); blanklabel.Show();"

Comment: where is the reference to the other form?  And is that the template form createBlankLabel calling Show() from itself in it's own initializer?  Seems to be a lot of information missing

Comment: Sorry I couldn't include all the code as it is a few hundred lines long. @rudolf_franek controlmover is a class that makes the control resizable and movable at run time.

Comment: @rob I was trying different options, by calling the form at varying stages through the program. This is on the most recent attempt.

Comment: so controlSelector  and ControlMoverOrResizer are not really relevant for the question, are they?

Comment: thank you @rudolf_franek, your responses have been particularly relevant for the question! I guess this is the danger if you are given points for commenting... The controlMoverOrResizer is the pivotal part of the overall project. So apologies if it in some way offends you

Comment: @TerryRowan I'm sorry I don't feel offended in any way but I'm also sorry I don't really get what is the state of your exploration and question. Did you manage to solve your issue or not yet? Anyway there are no points for comments..